# Codeigniter PUT request

Tags: codeigniter, rest, put

I try make PUT request but i can't. My form.

```
 <form method="put" action="http://localhost/index.php/book">
     <input type="text" name="bookName" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
 </form>
```

My controller

```
<?php

   require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

   class Book extends REST_Controller {

        function index_put(){
            echo $this->put('bookName');
        }   

   }

?>
```

The problem is that do not show anything.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML standard [does not support](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/forms.html#attr-fs-method) `put` inside the `<form method="">` attribute, if you put anything else other than `post` or `get` it should be sent as a `GET` request according to spec.

The canonical workaround implemented by many framewrok for this is to include a hidden `_method` field in your form and put the actual HTTP verb there. It seems like you are using [this library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), and it does this [`_method` parameter](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/v2.5/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L388) workaround too.